# Develop C# code using the method.Develop a UNIT-test to verify the method works

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Write each sentence of the text in ascending order of the number of vowels in a word.error: none of the overloads of the "Letters" method accept arguments "1".

```
public class Vowels
{
    public string Letters()
    {

        string[] a = { "aeiouy" };
        Array.Sort(a);
        
    }
}
```

Unit-tests:

```
 [TestClass]
public class VowelsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void MethodSort_vowels_in_ascending_order()
    {
        string a = "Teest! Test!";
       
        string expected = "Test! Teest";
        

        Vowels t = new Vowels();
        int actual = t.Letters(a);



        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method `Letters()` with a parameter (`t.Letters(a)`), but it is defined without any parameters (`public string Letters() {}`).